# Combining two lists of different length to tuples at every nth element of the longer list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to combine two list to a list of tuples at every nth element of the longer list.

Example:

```
list1 = ['I', 'am']
list2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

to:
list3 = [('I', 'am', '1', '2', '3'), ('I', 'am', '4', '5', '6')]
```

Unfortunately I don't know a way to iterate through lists with a potentially pretty large amount of values in a way to achieve the result.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to do this?

Comment: Will the length of `list2` always be an integer multiple of `n`?

Comment: yes it always will be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy and paste the `grouper` recipe from itertools ([here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)) and then:

```
>>> tup = tuple(list1)
>>> [tup + group for group in grouper(list2, 3)]
[('I', 'am', '1', '2', '3'), ('I', 'am', '4', '5', '6')]
```

Comment: wasn't me, thank you for your solution, I will try it later

Comment: works perfect for what I want to do, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can find the length of the joined elements of `list1`, and use list slicing in a list comprehension:

```
list1 = ['I', 'am']
list2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
l = len(''.join(list1))
final_result = [(*list1, *list2[i:i+l]) for i in range(0, len(list2), l)]
```

Output:

```
[('I', 'am', '1', '2', '3'), ('I', 'am', '4', '5', '6')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['I', 'am']
list2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

f = lambda l, n=3: [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
list(map(lambda l: tuple(list1 + l), f(list2)))
# [('I', 'am', '1', '2', '3'), ('I', 'am', '4', '5', '6')]
```